# log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.DoAppend going extremely slow

Tags: log4net

I have a web servce in which log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.DoAppend method is consistently slow at random times when using ADO Net Appender. I cannot find any evidence that my database server was down at the time, but this method suddenly starts taking up to 2 minutes, then all of a sudden goes back to being instant.

After a lot of googling, this doesn't seem to be a common issue, so I am turning to StackOverflow to see if anyone else has encountered slowness like this before and to see whether anyone has any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: How fast are you logging events? Is it possible you are logging events quicker than the database can process them? How you know that it is the DoAppend method that is slow?

Comment: Logging roughly 96,000 events per minute. The issue only seems to occur every few days and then clears itself without an app pool recycle or iis reset etc. I can see in App Dynamics that the DoAppend method is going slow, but the SendBuffer method is instantaneous during the issue, with 600+ SP calls taking less than 2 seconds combined, so I see no evidence of the database being under strain. Buffer size is currently 100, but the same issue occurred when it was set to 10.

Answer (score 1):

The ADO.NET appender can do buffering. Check the buffersize in your configuration. When it is slow, it is probably empting its buffer. Try a smaller buffer size.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Peter. Would you recommend trying a buffer size of 1? I've moved the buffer size up from 10 to 100 and many values in between those two values and the same issue eventually occurred on all settings with no noticeable pattern between the length of time the issue took to occur with higher or lower buffer sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have file write/modify permission in your log folder?If you have lack of permission that time log4net stack and hangs in do append method